# Create a 3d tensor from a pandas dataframe (pytorch)

Tags: pandas, pytorch

What is the easiest way (I am looking for the minimum number of code lines) to convert a pandas dataframe of 4 columns into a 3d tensor padding the missing values along the way.

```
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'Animal':['Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Dog'],
        'Country':["USA", "Canada", "USA", "Canada"],
        'Likes': ['Petting', 'Hunting', 'Petting', 'Petting'], 
         'Age':[1, 2, 3, 4]}

# there are no duplicate lines in terms of Animal, Country and Likes, so I do not need any aggregation function
  
# Create DataFrame
dfAnimals = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfAnimals
```

I want to create a 3d tensor with shape (2, 2, 2) --> (`Animal`, `Country`, `Likes`) and `Age` is the value. I also want to fill the missing values with 0

Answer (score 0):

There might be a solution with fewer lines and more optimized library calls, but this seems to do the trick:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd
import torch

data = ...
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

CAT = df.columns.tolist()
CAT.remove("Age")

# encode categories as integers and extract the shape
shape = []
for c in CAT:
    shape.append(len(df[c].unique()))
    df[c] = df[c].astype("category").cat.codes
shape = tuple(shape)

# get indices as tuples and corresponding values
idx = [tuple(t) for t in df.values[:,:-1]]
values = df.values[:,-1]

# init final matrix with zeros and fill it from indices
A = np.zeros(shape)
for i, v in zip(idx,values):
    A[i] = v

# convert to pytorch tensor
A = torch.tensor(A)
print(A)
```

```
tensor([[[0., 0.],
         [0., 1.]],

        [[2., 4.],
         [0., 3.]]], dtype=torch.float64)
```